# mt_srand() and srand() - is it necessary to reset the seed to a random number?

Tags: php, c

I have a function in my code that uses a seed to get a predictable (based on the seed) set of random numbers.

```
$seed = 1234;
mt_srand($seed);

echo mt_rand(0,10);
echo mt_rand(0,10);
echo mt_rand(0,10);
echo mt_rand(0,10);
```

Is it necessary to call mt_srand() at the end of my function to reset it back to a random seed once I'm done with it?

Comment: Why is your function calling `mt_srand()`? I'm curious if there might be a better way of going about things entirely.

Comment: @duskwuff It's a good question. For example, I want to generate the same set of random numbers for a given user (but still random/different for different users). So in that case, they can use the user_id as a seed.

Comment: Like, you just need some set of random numbers associated with the user? You might want to consider something like `unpack("LLLL", sha1($salt . $user_id))` if so (where `$salt` is a fixed value you use to get this set of numbers).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @duskwuff. Will take that into consideration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The state of `mt_rand()` is global — if your function sets it to a fixed value, it will stay in that state after your function exits. While it's not ideal to call `mt_srand()`, as that would disrupt any other function that's trying to set a fixed seed, it's still preferable to leaving the random number generator in a non-random state.

Comment: if you need the same set of pseudo-random numbers generated (exmp: you have a test case that tests random inputs, but it is failing, so you fix the mt_rand so every run is the same), can you accomplish it like this: call mt_rand(20) at he beginning of the function and mt_rand() at the end?